# buildr: specify project base dir

Tags: buildr

I'm new to buildr so apologies if this is trivial.

I refactored all my projects so that they now follow the Apache convention (src/main/java etc) but I have one big java project which is divided into three logical sub projects.

In other words my directory structure looks something like this:

```
[root]
  buildfile
  [project-a]
  [project-b]
  [directory-for-projects-c-d-e]
     [project-c]
     [project-d]
     [project-e]
```

Each individual project follows the Apache convention, but the problem is that buildr thinks [directory-for-projects-c-d-e] is, itself, a project.

I managed to use base_dir= to set the base directory for projects c,d and e - but buildr does not output to the correct target directories for these 3 projects.

Is there a quick fix for this? Or do I need to define a new layout just to specify a different base_dir? (seems odd, if that's the case).

I would prefer not to have to move projects c,d,e up one level because the current logical grouping makes a lot of sense.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `base_dir=`, here is the [doc](http://buildr.apache.org/rdoc/Buildr/Project.html#method-i-base_dir-3D).

Comment: I mentioned base_dir in the original question, so no, not really.

Comment: Hmm sorry I missed that. So normally the target directory is computed based off the base_dir. Where is the output made for those 3 ? Are you doing anything special ?

Comment: If I remember correctly I just bit the bullet and moved the 3 sub projects up a level